# amp-html: mustache script is marked as user-authored scripts

Tags: amp-html

I'm trying to create an amp-list with my custom template, using amp-mustache template engine, according to this official document: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-mustache

However, Google AMP Search Console marked my AMP page as invalid, due to AMP-mustache script is marked as invalid (user-authored scripts), meanwhile I just follow official document.

[image]

How can I fix this?
Sorry my english isn't good.

Comment: please show your source if you expect us to analyze a problem

Comment: Thank you so much. After 1 day read carefully documents again I've found my error. `custom-template="amp-mustache"` instead of `custom-element="amp-mustache"` solves the problem. Just a bit modify inside official AMP plugin for wordpress :)

Answer (score 1):

According to this [thread](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/892), one critical aspect of use of template languages in AMP is that it requires a valid DOM. However, `template` element gives this assurance, but validator has to confirm. Although it is valid in Mustache, it will not allow:

- Expressions on element names are not allowed, e.g. `<{{tagName}}></{{tagName}}>` is invalid.
- Expressions on element attribute names are not allowed, e.g.  is invalid. Notice that attribute value expressions are perfectly valid.

Be noted that there are certain [Restrictions](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-mustache) that you need to follow and this might be the reason why your AMP page is invalid.

> Like all AMP templates, `amp-mustache` templates are required to be well-formed DOM fragments. This means that among other things, you can't use `amp-mustache` to:
>
> - Calculate tag name. E.g. `{{tagName}}` is not allowed.
> - Calculate attribute name. E.g. `<div =something>` is not allowed.
> - Output arbitrary HTML using `{{unescaped}}}`. The output of "triple-mustache" is sanitized to only allow formatting tags such as `<b>`, `<i>`, and so on.
>
> Notice also that because the body of the `template` has to be specified within the template element, it is impossible to specify `{{&var}}` expressions - they will always be escaped as `{{&amp;var}}`. The triple-mustache `{{var}}}` has to be used for these cases.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. After 1 day read carefully documents again I've found my error. `custom-template="amp-mustache"` instead of `custom-element="amp-mustache"` solves the problem. Just a bit modify inside official AMP plugin for wordpress :)